# BluetoothDevice getmethod NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

I am creating new connection class for Bluetooth device on Android Studio.I cant figure out why thrown exception in design time.

```
public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device,MainActivity activity,BluetoothAdapter adapter) {
    mainActivity=activity;
    bluetoothAdapter=adapter;
    BluetoothSocket temp = null;
    bluetoothDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        temp = (BluetoothSocket)bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",int.class).invoke(bluetoothDevice,1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bluetoothSocket = temp;
}
```

[image: Android studio look]

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
temp = (BluetoothSocket)bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",int.class).invoke(bluetoothDevice,1);
```

has the potential to throw a NoSuchMethodException. You do not have a `catch` block to handle this exception. So you have to add another `catch` block under your existing `catch` block as follows:

```
catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
    //Insert code here
}
```

Also, that line of code will later throw the following exceptions so it is best to handle them as well: `IllegalAccessException`, and `InvocationTargetException`. Thus, your `try-catch` blocks should be as follows:

```
try {
    temp = (BluetoothSocket)bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",int.class).invoke(bluetoothDevice,1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(NoSuchMethodException ex){
    //Insert code here
}
catch(IllegalAccessException e){
    //Insert code here
}
catch(InvocationTargetException e){
    //Insert code here
}
```

Alternatively, you could handle every single exception with the general `Exception` class. In this case, your code should look something like this:

```
try {
    temp = (BluetoothSocket)bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",int.class).invoke(bluetoothDevice,1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Enter code here
}
```